# Rails: 'Load More' button with Ajax & Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a "load more" ajax pagination, with Kaminari.
I'm using this code :

```
class BienvenueController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Admin::Article.page(1).per(2)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js 
    end
  end
end

# Bienvenue#index

<div class="container"  style="min-width:<%= @width %>px">
<%= render "shared/articles" %>
<%= link_to_next_page @articles, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>"load_more_link" %>
```

```
# Shared/articles

<% @articles.each do |a| %>
        <article class="<%= a.rubrique.color %>">
                <div class="sharing">
                    <%= image_tag "facebook-32.png" %>
                </div>
                <p class="color<%= a.rubrique.color %>"><i>Le <%= I18n.localize(a.created_at, :format => :long) %>  par David Perrotin</i></p>
                <h1><%= a.titre %></h1>
                <div class="excerpt">
                    <%= a.chapo.html_safe %>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <%= image_tag a.mainphoto.url(:medium), :width=>"100%" %>
                </div>
                <div class="contenu">
                    <%= a.contenu.html_safe %>
                </div>
                <div class="readmore">
                    <%= link_to "Continuer la lecture", article_path(a) %>
                </div>
            </article>
        <% end %>

# index.js.erb

$('.container').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/articles')%>");
$('#load_more_link').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@articles,    'Load More', :remote => true, :id=>'load_more_link'))%>");
```

But the problem is that when I click on "Load More", it always shows the two same articles, the partial is never refreshed with two more articles, like I would like.

Comment: Shouldn't this `@articles = Admin::Article.page(1).per(2)` be  `@articles = Admin::Article.page(params[:page]).per(2)`

Comment: I'm stupid. Thank you very much for your fast answer, that works !

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into an issue with this that might help others. Depending on your version of jQuery, don't use `replaceWith` on the `#load_more_link` in `index.js.erb`.

There is a regression (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13401) that an empty replaceWith does nothing, so on the very last page of your set, the `link_to_next` will be empty, making the line: `$('#load_more_link').replaceWith('');` and thus will not replace the last "more" button, so you'll continually load the last page of your data set.

Fixed by updating jQuery version or use `empty().html('...')` instead of replaceWith.